# Stacked Chart Format Syncfusion

Tags: c#, charts, syncfusion

I should have 5 columns which stack the second and third values.

Instead, I get two columns:

The first stacking the second value of each column.

The second column stacking the last 4 values.

I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong. I have been battling with Syncfusion for the past week trying to get, what I would have thought to be, fairly basic slides built for a client. However, this has been a nightmare so far.

```
// Creates the two charts that go on the presentation

IPresentationChart chart = slide.Charts.AddChart(150, 100, 300, 125);

// Set data values

chart.ChartData.SetValue(1, 1, date1);
chart.ChartData.SetValue(2, 1, date2);
chart.ChartData.SetValue(3, 1, date3);
chart.ChartData.SetValue(4, 1, date4);
chart.ChartData.SetValue(5, 1, date5);
chart.ChartData.SetValue(1, 2, mains1);
chart.ChartData.SetValue(2, 2, mains2);
chart.ChartData.SetValue(3, 2, mains3);
chart.ChartData.SetValue(4, 2, mains4);
chart.ChartData.SetValue(5, 2, mains5);
chart.ChartData.SetValue(1, 3, variance1);
chart.ChartData.SetValue(2, 3, variance2);
chart.ChartData.SetValue(3, 3, variance3);
chart.ChartData.SetValue(4, 3, variance4);
chart.ChartData.SetValue(5, 3, variance5);

// Chart 1
// Set data range, Title and Category settings

chart.PrimaryCategoryAxis.CategoryType = OfficeCategoryType.Category;
chart.ChartTitle = "";
chart.ChartArea.Fill.Transparency = 0.5;

IOfficeChartSerie serie= chart.Series.Add(date1);
serie.Values = chart.ChartData[1, 2, 1, 3];
serie.SerieType = OfficeChartType.Column_Stacked;

IOfficeChartSerie serie2 = chart.Series.Add(date2);
serie2.Values = chart.ChartData[2, 2, 2, 3];
serie2.SerieType = OfficeChartType.Column_Stacked;

IOfficeChartSerie serie3 = chart.Series.Add(date3);
serie3.Values = chart.ChartData[3, 2, 3, 3];
serie3.SerieType = OfficeChartType.Column_Stacked;

IOfficeChartSerie serie4 = chart.Series.Add(date4);
serie4.Values = chart.ChartData[4, 2, 4, 3];
serie4.SerieType = OfficeChartType.Column_Stacked;

IOfficeChartSerie serie5 = chart.Series.Add(date5);
serie5.Values = chart.ChartData[5, 2, 5, 3];
serie5.SerieType = OfficeChartType.Column_Stacked;

chart.PlotArea.Layout.ManualLayout.Height = 0.9;
chart.PlotArea.Layout.ManualLayout.Width = 1;
chart.PlotArea.Layout.ManualLayout.Left = 0;
chart.PlotArea.Layout.ManualLayout.Top = 0;

chart.PrimaryCategoryAxis.CategoryLabels = chart.ChartData[1, 1, 5, 1];
chart.Legend.IncludeInLayout = false;
chart.HasLegend = false;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of columns in the column-stacked chart depends on the number of categories available in the data range. In your code snippet, there are only two category values. So, two columns are displayed in the column - stacked chart.

```
Example: serie.Values = chart.ChartData[1, 2, 1, 3];
```

Here the category values are [ 1, 2 ] and [ 1 , 3 ].

We have also manually created a chart in Microsoft PowerPoint for your scenario (in your code snippet) and attached the created PowerPoint presentation in below link. 
http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/pp/Chart1370190114.pptx

We have also modified your code snippet to display the 5 columns. Please find the code snippet as below.

```
IPresentationChart chart = slide.Charts.AddChart(150, 100, 300, 125); 
chart.ChartType = OfficeChartType.Column_Stacked; 
chart.ChartData.SetValue(1, 1, "4355"); 
chart.ChartData.SetValue(2, 1, "4356"); 
chart.ChartData.SetValue(3, 1, "4357"); 
chart.ChartData.SetValue(4, 1, "4358"); 
chart.ChartData.SetValue(5, 1, "4359"); 
chart.ChartData.SetValue(1, 2, "6"); 
chart.ChartData.SetValue(2, 2, "7"); 
chart.ChartData.SetValue(3, 2, "8"); 
chart.ChartData.SetValue(4, 2, "9"); 
chart.ChartData.SetValue(5, 2, "10"); 
chart.ChartData.SetValue(1, 3, "11"); 
chart.ChartData.SetValue(2, 3, "12"); 
chart.ChartData.SetValue(3, 3, "13"); 
chart.ChartData.SetValue(4, 3, "14"); 
chart.ChartData.SetValue(5, 3, "15"); 
//Set data range, Title and category settings 
chart.PrimaryCategoryAxis.CategoryType = OfficeCategoryType.Category; 
chart.ChartTitle = ""; 
chart.ChartArea.Fill.Transparency = 0.5; 
IOfficeChartSerie serie = chart.Series.Add("date1"); 
//Selecting data from first row second column to fifth row second column 
//ChartData[startRow,startColumn,endRow,endColumn] 
serie.Values = chart.ChartData[1, 2, 5, 2]; //Modified the data range to have 5 columns
serie.SerieType = OfficeChartType.Column_Stacked; 
IOfficeChartSerie serie2 = chart.Series.Add("date2"); 
//Selection data from first row third column to fifth row third column 
serie2.Values = chart.ChartData[1, 3, 5, 3]; //Modified the data range to have 5 columns
serie2.SerieType = OfficeChartType.Column_Stacked; 
chart.PlotArea.Layout.ManualLayout.Height = 0.9; 
chart.PlotArea.Layout.ManualLayout.Width = 1; 
chart.PlotArea.Layout.ManualLayout.Left = 0; 
chart.PlotArea.Layout.ManualLayout.Top = 0; 
chart.PrimaryCategoryAxis.CategoryLabels = chart.ChartData[1, 1, 5, 1]; 
chart.Legend.IncludeInLayout = true; 
chart.HasLegend = false;
```

**Output document for the above modified code snippet**:

http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/pp/Output-549061229.pptx

Please let us know if you need further assistance on this,

Note : I work for Syncfusion Software Private Limited